# library that identifies similar images

Tags: image-processing, compare, extract

I want to determine how similar 2 images are.
The images may have been scaled, cropped, etc, so a simple pixel comparison won't work.

I have had a look around and there are a lot of academic papers on this topic but they don't release their code. So, do you know of a released library that can compare images (for Linux and Windows)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across this fantastic list of software for computer vision: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cil/v-source.html

And decided to look at these 2 tools in more detail:

- http://libpuzzle.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle
- http://appsrv.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~jkzhu/felib.html

Comment: Richard - What did you ultimately decide to do? I'm looking into the same thing and would like to benefit from your experience.

Comment: @hoju it's an old question but still... Can you provide a short info about the links you have provided, in case any one of them would be dead ?