# Find Edges with ImageJ Programmatically

Tags: java, edge-detection, imagej

I want to use find edges option of the **ImageJ**, have the edges-found array and save it to another file programatically.

```
ImagePlus ip1 = IJ.openImage("myimage.jpg");
ImageProcessor ip = new ColorProcessor(ip1.getWidth(), ip1.getHeight());
ip.findEdges();
```

However, the function **findEdges** is abstract and I can't have the edge-found image.

**EDIT:**

I wrote the following lines:

```
ip.findEdges();
BufferedImage bimg = ip.getBufferedImage();
```

However, when I try to print out the RGB values of the BufferedImage, it only prints "-16777216" for each pixel RGB.

Comment: See also this related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14170238/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got the solution, the problem was that I didn't connect the ColorProcessor with the image.

```
ColorProcessor ip = new ColorProcessor(ImageIO.read(new File("my_image.jpg")));
ip.findEdges();
BufferedImage bimg = ip.getBufferedImage();
```

Comment: If you do this, you can declare `ip` as `ImageProcessor` like you did in your question

Comment: The left hand side of the initialization don't matter here, as it's just a reference to a memory block. Right hand side is the actual class the operations will be looked up first, so what you say is right.

Answer (score 0):

ImageProcessor is an abstract class, that lets the derived classes provide the appropriate implementation.  You need to declare `ip` as type `ColorProcessor`:

```
ColorProcessor ip = new ColorProcessor(ip1.getWidth(), ip1.getHeight()); 
ip.findEdges();
```

Comment: How can I reach the edge-found array? I also initialize it with ColorProcessor, it will look at ColorProcessor's functions in vtable first, I guess.

Comment: I am no ImageJ expert, but looking at the [documentation](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ColorProcessor.html) it seems there is no way to do that.  Rather `findEdges()` applies a transformation to the image, so that when you get the image (e.g. via `createImage()`), you will see the edges detected, instead of the original image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, but I got the solution. If interested, posted it below.