# Find array of edges with imageJ

Tags: java, imagej, edges

I have already found edges of an image thanks to imageJ library.

Now, I'd like to get an array which would contain these edges.

There is a topic about it here but i couldn't comment and there wasn't the answer:
[Find Edges with ImageJ Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652578/find-edges-with-imagej-programatically)

Comment: What will you do with the array of edges?

Comment: My goal is listing these (horizontal) edges.
Example: consider an image where I have found edges (with methods of ij you used in your post). If a line appears as an edge, I would like to list it: it would be a segment with a starting point and an end point.
Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes. With ImageJ you can only get edge-detected version of the image, not the edges, as I know. First, get the edge-detected version of the image. Non-edge pixels will be black, edge pixels will be different. You need to find start and end points of these by yourself.

Comment: I know but it seemed you did it in your post, not finding precisely start and end points, but array of edges.
Thanks btw

Comment: The title of my question mislead you, I see. I only found the edge-detected image. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [*§29.3 Find Edges*](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-29.html#toc-Subsection-29.3), the command uses the [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator). Each point of the final image is the [magnitude of the gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#Formulation) of the horizontal and vertical convolutions. A copy of the whole array is returned by the `get*Array()` methods of the chosen [`ImageProcessor`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html); the individual elements of the array can be accessed using the various `get*()` methods.

Addendum: You say, "My aim is to get the edges. My problem is not getting each pixel value."

[*Edge detection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) is not [trivial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection#Why_edge_detection_is_a_non-trivial_task); it is typically a multi-stage process. The array of magnitudes is merely the *initial* result of applying the [first-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection#Other_first-order_methods) Sobel operator. The next [stages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection#Thresholding_and_linking) in the pipeline, e.g. thresholding, linking, thinning, depend on your goal.

Comment: True, but my aim is to get the edges. My problem is not getting each pixel value.
Ismet Alkan user seems to hava managed this operation, but I don't know how to contact him and I can't comment his post.

Comment: I've elaborated above; please edit your question to clarify what result you expect.

Comment: My goal is: find connex component. Each major edge would be a connex component which could be referenced.

Comment: @Archos007: I don't understand _connex component_. Please edit your question to include a link and for others to see your clarification in the [active queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/163188).

Comment: In my first post, there is a link. And my goal is about what users talk in the last posts. One of them says he managed to find edge-found array, but he doesn't explain how. And I can't comment because I've just joined the site.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you'll get a different answer, but [editing your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) is a way to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know this is old, but this needs an answer. Using imageJ programatically

```
 float edgePixels[][];
 ImagePlus imp = null;
 Opener op = new Opener();
 imp =  op.openImage("lib/EP07-J.jpg");
 ImageProcessor improc = imp.getProcessor().duplicate();

 improc.medianFilter();
 improc.findEdges();
 edgePixels = improc.getFloatArray();
```

Congrats, you now have a multi-dimensional array representing the pixels after edge detection.