# Is there a way in selenium to compare screen shots using (TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs method?

Tags: java, compare, screenshot, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to compare screens using selenium web driver java. Is there any API to compare? Able to capture and save images.

Comment: With ``getScreenshotAs`` you can capture and save a screenshot. By comparing you mean programmaticaly? If so, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644960/java-library-to-compare-image-similarity) might help

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in selenium to compare screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV there's some functionalities who allow you to compare image.

Have a nice day