# find matching image on click of part of the image

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am looking for a bestway to find the matching image (out of set of stored images) on click of the part of image.

For example if I have image of person holding pen, if I click on pen portion of the image, i should be able to retrieve the pen image from the set of predefined images in this case i should be able to retrieve pen image if exists.

I am willing to know what java/javascript based framework is suitable for this and best way of doing it.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: You could use OpenCV http://opencv.org/ but that's far from easy...

Comment: try this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644960/java-library-to-compare-image-similarity

Comment: if you have the coords for the different artifacts and its a html page, use the map and area tags

Answer (score 1):

The [area tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/area) was designed for projects like this. You can use the area tag to specify a region of your image that when clicked will go to a link or run a javascript function to bring up the specific image. Here is an [example](http://www.suu.edu/campmap/campus.html).