# How to implement Face Recognition in Java using images?

Tags: java, image-processing, javacv, face-recognition, biometrics

How can I compare two face images, whether they belong to same person or not.

Let me explain:

The code will get two images as input and recognize it and compare them. If it belongs to same person (even though takes at different time) it will return true or else false.

Like this:

```
    boolean Compare (Image a,Image b)
    {
     if (Both_are_same-person's) 
       return true;
     else return false;
    }
```

Given images may be in any format like jpg,png,bmp,tiff.

Comment: Defenitely a library :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644960/java-library-to-compare-image-similarity

Comment: Face recognition is a very big topic, and cannot be answered in a single question. You need to research on it and try to implement.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenCV](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) should be useful for your requirement.

> OpenCV is an open source computer vision library originally developed
>   by Intel. It is free for commercial and research use under a BSD
>   license. The library is cross-platform, and runs on Mac OS X, Windows
>   and Linux. It focuses mainly towards real-time image processing, as
>   such, if it finds Intel's Integrated Performance Primitives on the
>   system, it will use these commercial optimized routines to accelerate
>   itself.
>
> This implementation is not a complete port of OpenCV. Currently, this
>   library supports :
>
> real-time capture video file import basic image treatment (brightness,
>   contrast, threshold, …)
>   **object detection (face, body, …)** blob detection

Comment: Can u give me a code for it if possible ?

Comment: @user2625739 If you follow the OpenCV link, there are sample codes zip available for you to understand and implement it.

Comment: Please give me that OpenCV link or javaCV link

Comment: @user2625739 First word of my answer is a link to OpenCV :-) Here it is again : http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/