# Best way to detect duplicate files in a certain folder android

Tags: java, android, file, image-processing, duplicates

What is the best way to detect duplicate files in android, currently I am using files MD5# to detect duplicates, it works well but it is very slow and I don't know is it safer to user MD5# for detecting duplicates. Also it is not useful in the case of images when its resolution or format is different

Is there any better way to do this? I mean by using any library or algorithms

My case is that I was trying to build a duplicate detection app like the many in [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/search_results_cluster_apps?clp=ggERCg9kdXBsaWNhdGUgZmlsZXM%3D%3AS%3AANO1ljId920&hl=en) as a part of my project

Comment: Actually this is not Android specific

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?

If two image files have different formats and resolutions, then they are NOT duplicates, are they ?

1. You could speed up the MD5 process by first checking the **file-size**. If the file size is different, then there is no need to checksum, they are guaranteed to be different.
2. Perhaps build a **binary tree using bits** at specific offsets? For example, bit 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,128,1024,2048. Then only checksum files attached to the same node, that are the same file-size... Files attached to different nodes are guaranteed to be different.

We could help more if we knew more about the problem you are you trying to solve.

Comment: @cds84 added my case in the question itself

Comment: In that case, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644960/java-library-to-compare-image-similarity.